# How do I get to The Bridge?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I am in Halloweentown, and the walkthrough I am using tells me that I am supposed to go to the Bridge area next, but it is incredibly vague on the directions of how I actually get there.

I am lost and wandering around and beating on Heartless, and I would really like to get to where I need to go.

How do I get to the Bridge?

Comment: [It's right here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)!

Comment: I knew someone was going to do that. I knew it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been quite a while since I've played, but I did manage to find [this guide.](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/kingdom-hearts/halloween-town)

To reach the Bridge, you must first go to Moonlight Hill.

> look for a tombstone at the base of the hill that you can examine. Use it to extend the hill and get over the wall.

So, once you're in the Moonlight Hill area, look around for a gravestone you can examine. Examining and using this gravestone should extend a path, enabling you to enter the Bridge. Just make sure you're ready to fight some Heartless!

Comment: Hea...heartless?!  In Kingdom Hearts?!  D: